# Mais de um Campo data em Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Bom dia.

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
<form id="enviavenda" method="POST" action="" autocomplete="off">
    <input class="input_codBarras" id="codBarras" name="codBarras" type="number" />
    <input class="input_quantidade" id="on2Focus" name="quant" type="text" />
    <input id="btn_cadVenda" type="submit" value="enviar" style="display: none;">
</form>    

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            var newcodBarras = $("#codBarras").val();
            var newquantidade = $("#on2Focus").val();
            var sdata = { codBarras : newcodBarras, quantidade : newquantidade }
            $('#enviavenda').submit(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    url: '../arquivos/php/caixaCadastraVenda.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: sdata,
                    success: function(data){
                        $('.recebeDados').html(data);
                    }
                });
                $("#codBarras").val('');
                return false;
            });
        });
</script>
```

Problema:

Os Campos que foram inseridos nas variáveis jQuery não estão sendo passados para a página da url. Só funciona quando eu passo

```
data: $("#codBarras").serialize(),
```

Porém preciso passar dois campos inputs (ou mais).

No arquivo caixaCadastraVenda.php , quando chamo o $_POST['quantidade'] ou $_POST['codBarras'] apresenta erro que não existe esse campo.

**Como faço para passar mais de uma variável no data do Ajax?**

Comment: O ajax está funcionando ou a página está sendo recarregada?

Comment: A página não está sendo recarregada conforme comando do script return false, porém o cadastro no banco de dados não acontece pois o PHP informa que o arquivo $_POST["quantidade"] não existe.

Comment: Se a página não está sendo recarregada, a princípio é só colocar as 3 linhas que começam com `var ...` dentro do submit. você está pegando dados que não foram preenchidos ainda e está usando no form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está criando o objeto fora do evento submit, com isso ele sempre vai ficar vazio. Basta colocar dentro que irá pegar os valores no momento do submit:

```
$(function(){
   $('#enviavenda').submit(function(){
      var newcodBarras = $("#codBarras").val();
      var newquantidade = $("#on2Focus").val();
      var sdata = { codBarras : newcodBarras, quantidade : newquantidade }
       $.ajax({
           url: '../arquivos/php/caixaCadastraVenda.php',
           type: 'POST',
           data: sdata,
           success: function(data){
               $('.recebeDados').html(data);
           }
       });
       $("#codBarras").val('');
       return false;
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Passe para formData, Vale ressaltar que no php quando usado o formData, você precisa usar os mesmos names do HTML, ou seja codBarras e quant

```
<form id="enviavenda" method="POST" action="" autocomplete="off">
    <input class="input_codBarras" id="codBarras" name="codBarras" type="number" />
    <input class="input_quantidade" id="on2Focus" name="quant" type="text" />
    <input id="btn_cadVenda" type="submit" value="enviar" style="display: none;">
</form>    

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            //Serializa o formulário
            var sdata = new FormData(document.getElementById('enviavenda'));

            $('#enviavenda').submit(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    url: '../arquivos/php/caixaCadastraVenda.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: sdata,
                    success: function(data){
                        $('.recebeDados').html(data);
                    }
                });
                $("#codBarras").val('');
                return false;
            });
        });
</script>
```

NO PHP

```
<?php  $quantidade = $_POST['quant']; $codB = $_POST['codBarras']; ?>
```

Comment: O `FormData` não vai funcionar se não for alterado o PHP, pois no código do AP ele usa `quantidade` e no form está `quant`. Claro que isso é apenas um detalhe, mas sem mencioná-lo sua resposta fica incompleta.

Comment: Pronto amigo obrigado pela observação @fernandosavio

Answer (score 0):

Caso o seu php estaja esperando um model

Json:

```
$(function(){            

            $('#enviavenda').submit(function(){
             var modelnome= {
              codBarras :  $("#codBarras").val(),
              quantidade :$("#on2Focus").val()
              }

                $.ajax({
                    url: '../arquivos/php/caixaCadastraVenda.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    data: JSON.stringify(modelnome),
                    success: function(data){
                        $('.recebeDados').html(data);
                    }
                });
                $("#codBarras").val('');
                return false;
            });
        });
```

Form:

```
$(function(){
        $('#enviavenda').submit(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: '../arquivos/php/caixaCadastraVenda.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: data: $('form#enviavenda').serialize(),
                success: function(data){
                    $('.recebeDados').html(data);
                }
            });
            $("#codBarras").val('');
            return false;
        });
    });
```